# Too many re-renders/infinite loop - setting state in mapping function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to map through items in my cart and compare the id of the item to the id returned in the data object, and then displaying some info on the browser such as quantity for each item etc. I am also trying to add a total cart items display element, however, when I add the quantity of each item in the cart (eg one item has quantity of 3, another has 1 etc) and try to set the state within the mapping function, I get a re-render error. I understand from reading online that its because when you set state, the component re-renders, however, I am unsure how to set state with the total quantity of items in the cart without setting state from within the function.

I also tried declaring the variable outside the mapping function and adding to that variable on each iteration, but that does not work either.

IF i console log cartItemsTotal within the mapping function, I get the correct value of the addition of all the items being mapped through's quantity.

If I console log it outside the mapping function, its always 0. Is this because of scope? You cant  manipulate a variable outside of the scope of the function?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
const CartIconSummary = ({data}) => {
  const [cartQuantity, setCartQuantity] = useState()
  const deleteCart = useCartDelete()
  const cart = useCart()
  
  let cartTotal = 0
  let vat = cartTotal * .23.toFixed(2)
  let cartItemsTotal = 0

  const displayCartItems = () => {
    setCartQuantity(cartItemsTotal)
    return cart && cart.map((cartItem, index) => {
      return data && data.map((dataItem) => {
          if(cartItem.id === dataItem.id) {
            cartTotal = cartTotal + dataItem.price * cartItem.quantity
            vat = vat + (dataItem.price * cartItem.quantity) * .23
            cartItemsTotal = cartItemsTotal + cartItem.quantity
            setCartQuantity(cartItemsTotal)
          return (
              <div key={index} className={`${className}CartItemContainer`}>
                  <div className={`${className}ImageContainer`}> 
                      <img className={`${className}Image`} src={data ? `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}${dataItem.cartImage.slice(1)}` : ""} alt="cart-item-preview"/>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div className={`${className}CartItemNamePriceContainer`}> 
                      <div className={`${className}CartItemName`}> 
                          {dataItem.shortName}
                      </div>
                      <div className={`${className}CartItemPrice`}>
                          ${dataItem.price}
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className={`${className}CartItemQuantity`}> 
                      x {cartItem.quantity}
                  </div>
              </div>
          )
          } else {
              return ""
          }
      })
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
    <div className={`${className}CartDeleteContainer`}> 
        <div className={`${className}CartQuantity`}> CART({cartQuantity ? cartQuantity : 0}) </div>
        <div className={`${className}CartDelete`} onClick={() => deleteCart([])}> Remove all </div>
    </div>
    {displayCartItems()}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you call `setCartQuantity` inside the function `displayCartItems`, which means that whenever the component renders the function `displayCartItems` will run again as well. That means when the function `displayCartItems` executes, it will change the state `cartQuantity` with `setCartQuantity` and if a state changes the whole component will re-render, which means `displayCartItems` will be exectued again.

To solve this, you should use a `useEffect` hook and add `cartItemsTotal` in the dependency array so that `setCartQuantity` is only executed when `cartItemsTotal` changes.

Comment: Thanks You S J! This works. However, I am unsure why it works. If I console log cartQuantity just below where it is declared, the value stays at 0 as if the addition to cartQuantity that occurs in displayCartItems function is not adding the value and passing it to the variable as declared outside displayCartItems. 

Can you enlighten me?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what the situation exactly is. Could you share the whole code?